# when I press the button y the control key is pressed and y is not digta

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-mate, xev

I'm using a hp 246 g6 notebook and when I press the y key it says I pressed the ctrl as shown in the xev log below

```
KeyPress event, serial 79, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x78c, subw 0x0, time 2418353, (310,105), root:(321,160),
    state 0x4, keycode 29 (keysym 0x79, y), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (19) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (19) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 79, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x78c, subw 0x0, time 2418438, (310,105), root:(321,160),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 79, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x78c, subw 0x0, time 2418443, (310,105), root:(321,160),
    state 0x0, keycode 29 (keysym 0x79, y), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (79) "y"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I tried to change it with a script but the error persists

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 29 = y"
```

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?  (ie. rule out hardware..)  or at least a different cable (assuming cable can be swapped, or fresh batteries etc).  You haven't provided release details.

Comment: It's a notebook keyboard and when open virtual keyboard to show keys is pressed only y has been pressed

Comment: I tried using another keyboard and it's working as expected, I don't believe it is a hardware problem.

Comment: You've still not provided release details, but I'd boot a different OS/release (ideally a different *stack* to your current *unstated* stack) using *live* media and test there. If the response is the same using the different software stack - it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem change keyboard because the current is broken